# API design : Need help for URLs

Tags: mongodb, api

I'm designing a new website. Before i start to code, i'm learning a lot about api and nosql database (as i'm used to sql but i want to try with mongoDB).

In mongoDB, i'll have a 'user' document like that :

```
{
   firstname: 'xxxxxxx',
   lastname:  'xxxxxxx',
   projects: [
      {
         name: 'project xxxxxxx',
         participants: [], // array of friends into this project
         operations: [
            { title: 'Title OP xxxxxxx', contributors: [] },
            { title: 'Title OP xxxxxxx', contributors: [] },
            { title: 'Title OP xxxxxxx', contributors: [] }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I was wondering two things :

1. Should `projects.participants`and `projects.operations.contributors` be references to other users ?
2. For the API, should i do something like :
   `GET /users/:id_user

   GET /users/:id_user/projects/:id_project

   GET /users/:id_user/projects/:id_project/operations/:id_operation`
   (should my API always start with `users` ?)

If you ever have a better solution I will be glad to know.

Thanks

EDIT 1 : I'll work on NodeJS with Express and i would like to have a REST API.

Comment: What suits you best? And also what makes the most sense here? Everything is in one "User" object with embedded data right? So if things are referenced generally by the "user" then it should make sense to include that identifier in all requests. If however other embedded items have their own "unique" identifiers, then it would be perfectly reasonable for them to have their own endpoints. But also beware. Nesting arrays within arrays is not a great design pattern Read [positional $ update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, **projects.participants** and **projects.operations.contributors** can be reference to other documents in the same collection. Each of these should refer to valid **_id** in the same collection.
2. can you please put some more light on how exactly are you creating your APIs? I mean which framework you are using as a wrapper to access mongoDB? May be then I can try to help more.

Comment: Ok for the first question. For second one, i'll use NodeJS with express.

Answer (score 0):

ok great!!!
So, **users** is your collection name. Its absolutely not necessary to start your API name with **users**. In node.js you can create a router, which will route your request to a particular js file and you can name it anything you want. Example:

use case: You want to expose 3 API
1. To access all the users. (exposed using url - /getallusers)
2. To access all the participants of the project.(exposed using url - /getparticipantsbyproject)
3. To access all the contributors in the operations.(exposed using url - /getcontributorsbyproject).

You can write all these APIs in your file called **myapi** and expose them.

Now, you can very well call these APIs from browser using below urls:

1. http://host:port/myapi/getallusers
2. http://host:port/myapi/getparticipantsbyproject
3. http://host:port/myapi/getcontributorsbyproject

Comment: Arf. I forgot to precise : i want to have a REST API ! I think what you propose do not follow rest api, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Its about RESTful API only. I mentioned 3 urls above which are nothing but RESTful API exposing different functionalities.